# Issue with Fragmented Data Block Transport implementation for LoRaWAN

Tags: c++, c

I´m working through the [LoRaWAN Fragmented Data Block Transport](https://content.cdntwrk.com/files/aT0xNDY0NjgzJnY9MSZpc3N1ZU5hbWU9dHMwMDQtMi0wLTAtZnJhZ21lbnRlZC1kYXRhLWJsb2NrLXRyYW5zcG9ydCZjbWQ9ZCZzaWc9MjM0OGMyZTljYWEwY2JlNTBiODEyMjM4ZTA5OGI5OTY%253D) documentation and I try to understand the logic behind the `matrix_line` function and the examples from the document (page 23 and further).

For this, I have ported the function from Matlab (page 31) to C (see the related parts below):

```
static bool is_power2(uint32_t Number)
{
    return (Number != 0) && ((Number & (Number - 1)) == 0);
}

static uint32_t prbs23(uint32_t x)
{
    uint32_t b0;
    uint32_t b1;

    b0 = (x & 0x00000001);
    b1 = (x & 0x00000020) >> 5;

    return (x >> 1) + ((b0 ^ b1) << 22);
}

static void matrix_line(uint8_t* p_Buf, int N, int M)
{
    uint32_t m;
    uint32_t x;
    uint32_t nb_coeff;
    uint32_t r;

    if(N <= M)
    {
        p_Buf[N] = 1;

        return;
    }

    m = 0;
    if(is_power2(M))
    {
        m = 1;
    }

    x = 1 + (1001 * N);

    nb_coeff = 0;
    while(nb_coeff < (M/2))
    {
        r = (1 << 16);

        while(r >= M)
        {
            x = prbs23(x);
            r = x % (M + m);
        }

        if(p_Buf[r + 1] == 0)
        {
            p_Buf[r + 1] = 1;
            nb_coeff += 1;
        }
    }
}

void main(void)
{
    uint8_t Buf[26];
    uint8_t M;
    uint8_t N;

    N = 26;
    M = 52;

    for(uint32_t i = 0; i < M; i++)
    {
        memset(Buf, 0, sizeof(Buf));

        matrix_line(Buf, i, N);

        for(uint32_t j = 0; j < N; j++)
        {
            printf("%u", Buf[j]);
        }

        printf("\n\r");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And I try it with the example specification `N = 26` and `M = 52` to get the image from the document

[image]

But my output looks as shown below:

```
01000000000000000000000000
00100000000000000000000000
00010000000000000000000000
00001000000000000000000000
00000100000000000000000000
00000010000000000000000000
00000001000000000000000000
00000000100000000000000000
00000000010000000000000000
00000000001000000000000000
00000000000100000000000000
00000000000010000000000000
00000000000001000000000000
00000000000000100000000000
00000000000000010000000000
00000000000000001000000000
00000000000000000100000000
00000000000000000010000000
00000000000000000001000000
00000000000000000000100000
00000000000000000000010000
00000000000000000000001000
00000000000000000000000100
00000000000000000000000010
00000000000000000000000001
00000000000000000000000000 <---
01010001101100110100011011
01111100010011010000011011
00000000110011001111011111
00101100001111001001010111
01111100100100100001001111
01110110001100000001011111
01010101110001101100011001
01101101010100101001010110
00111100110011100100010101
00010100011110011001110011
00001111000101001111110001
00110110001101001101001110
00010001000101011101111101
01101111011101001000100010
01010100111100110111010000
00001001111100110111011000
00110111000111011101000100
01000110111101110000100101
01101000100110101110011010
01010010101110011000011011
00110010111000000111110110
01011110100111011000010010
01111001101110100001100010
00001101011111011001010010
00000100111010011111010101
01001100100111101000110101
```

All lines, beginning with the marked one, aren´t correct. Where does the empty line come from? And why is every line after that line rolled to the right by one, I. e:

```
01010001101100110100011011
```

should be

```
10100011011001101000110110
```

Comment: It's not much, but... All the "lines" are "rolled to the right"... The mysterious row of all 0's is the 26th row. Compare the very first row with the image you've posted. Maybe this 2nd diagnosis will help you find the problem.

Comment: Have you considered using others code? https://github.com/Lora-net/LoRaMac-node/blob/ceb27e3ba4a0aa3b4d0fa22a53256a8766b8f1ce/src/apps/LoRaMac/common/LmHandler/packages/FragDecoder.c#L575 It looks like https://github.com/Lora-net/LoRaMac-node/blob/master/src/apps/LoRaMac/common/LmHandler/packages/FragDecoder.c#L530 SetParity is not `p_Buf[r + 1] = 1;` but rather some shifts. Please add missing includes to your code. `main` does not return `void`, and return 0 is there invalid.

Comment: I don't know Matlab at all, but maybe its arrays index from 1 and C indexes from 0? That might explain the shift. Note that all the lines are wrong (as mentioned by @Fe2O3), not just the later ones.

Comment: You can save a few clock cycles on branch checks with `return Number && !(Number & (Number - 1));` as your `is_power2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a hunch I changed the code as follows:

```
    uint8_t Buf[1 + 26];
    uint8_t M = 52;
    uint8_t N = 26;

    for(uint32_t i = 1; i <= M; i++) // 1 <= i <= M
    {
        memset(Buf, 0, sizeof(Buf));

        matrix_line(Buf, i, N);

        for(uint32_t j = 1; j <= N; j++) // 1 <= j <= N
        {
            printf("%u", Buf[j]);
        }

        printf("\n");
    }
```

This seemed to produce the desired result.

It's a small issue, but the function is receiving unsigned values as signed... This should be addressed.

Comment: Or, the other way, the original code can assign to `p_Buf[N - 1] = 1;` and `p_Buf[r] = 1;`.

Comment: Thanks. That solves the issue. I think I have found the difference between Matlab and C. Matlab arrays are indicated by 1 and not by zero as in C or other programming languages. Good to know that.